# Set the menu link as disabled by default

Tags: 7, routes

When I create a new node its menu link is enabled by default. I would like to enable it manually only in case if I need. 
Is there a way to set the checkbox in menu tree as uncheked by default?

Comment: version D7 or D6?

Comment: sorry, I use D7

Comment: when you check 'Provide a menu link' then its mean menu is enabled. try other options -unpublished node or -If you would like to enable it manually then edit node and enable

Comment: I'm affraid it will be too comlicated for my users :(

Comment: I found the solution: Disable Node Menu Item Module http://drupal.org/project/disable_node_menu_item, I don't know is it enough stable version but I hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this module, I guess that is what you want.

http://drupal.org/project/default_menu_link

Some details from the module's project page:

> Provides the user with a check box on all content types to set the "provide a menu link" value to true by default.
>
> This is basically a nice way to ensure the menu system is adhered to by all content authors.
>
> There is a similar module called menu_force that does just that. Whereas Menu Force mandates menu assignment, Default Menu Link merely changes the status of "Provide a Menu Link" to true. The user can still create content and choose to un-check this box. However, the default state (on node creation) will be true, and as long as you've set a default menu parent item, all content will be filed under that parent.

Comment: this module provides another option. I need to have a menu link but also I need to hide it in menu as I use Menu Views to create mega menu. By default all new content menu links appear in menu tree as enabled links destroying menu. I need to hide menu links

Comment: Thanks for share this module! It's small, but works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: Disable Node Menu Item Module drupal.org/project/disable_node_menu_item, I don't know is it enough stable version but I hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

By default, all menu items are "enabled." This means they display. Menu items can also be disabled though. A disabled menu item knows who its parent is, so the related sub-menu and breadcrumb will display. But - you don't have to necessarily clutter up your menu with another visible link. (Note: this is only really applicable to the main menu since that's what drives the sub-menu and breadcrumb.)

To create a **disabled menu** item:

1. Put the page/webform/list into the menu using the menu settings
   section of that content's edit form.
2. Click "Main menu" in the gray shortcut bar.
3. Find the menu item you want to disable.
4. Uncheck "enabled" next to it.
5. Click save at the bottom.

If you want to create a sub-menu below a page that doesn't display in the top menu, *just disable the top menu item and leave it's children enabled.*

Thank you.